# Verify reCaptcha v2 checkbox is ticked

Tags: php, recaptcha, server-side

I have tried for the majority of the day to get this working but all seem to not fully work with my code. I have a perfectly working sendmail script and just want to add in the google reCaptcha. So far it won't send contact form unless checkbox is ticked, but if it's not ticked my field validators don't work and there is not alert to tell the user to check the reCaptcha. But if all fields are filled out and checkbox is ticked it does echo the success message.

I have tried so many tuts on google and tried to follow the google developer docs but can't seem to decode my response correctly and get the if, else statements right!

```
//Checking For reCAPTCHA
$captcha;
if (isset($_POST['g-recaptcha-response'])) {
$captcha = $_POST['g-recaptcha-response'];
}
// Checking For correct reCAPTCHA
$response = 
file_get_contents("https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify? 
secret=SECRETKEY&response=" . $captcha . "&remoteip=" . 
$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);
if (!$captcha || $response.success == false) {
echo "Your CAPTCHA response was wrong.";
exit ;
} else {

session_cache_limiter( 'nocache' );
header( 'Expires: ' . gmdate( 'r', 0 ) );
header( 'Content-type: application/json' );
$to         = 'hi@shanemuirhead.co.uk';  // put your email here
$email_template = 'simple.html';
$subject    = strip_tags($_POST['vsubject']);
$email       = strip_tags($_POST['vemail']);
$name       = strip_tags($_POST['vname']);
$message    = nl2br( htmlspecialchars($_POST['vmessage'], ENT_QUOTES) );
$result     = array();

if(empty($name)){
    $result = array( 'response' => 'error', 'empty'=>'name', 'message'=>'<strong>Error!</strong>&nbsp; Name is empty.' );
    echo json_encode($result );
    die;
} 
if(empty($email)){
    $result = array( 'response' => 'error', 'empty'=>'email', 'message'=>'<strong>Error!</strong>&nbsp; Email is empty.' );
    echo json_encode($result );
    die;
} 
if(empty($message)){
     $result = array( 'response' => 'error', 'empty'=>'message', 'message'=>'<strong>Error!</strong>&nbsp; Message body is empty.' );
     echo json_encode($result );
     die;
}



$headers  = "From: " . $name . ' <' . $email . '>' . "\r\n";
$headers .= "Reply-To: ". $email . "\r\n";
$headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8\r\n";
$templateTags =  array(
    '{{subject}}' => $subject,
    '{{email}}'=>$email,
    '{{message}}'=>$message,
    '{{name}}'=>$name
    );
$templateContents = file_get_contents( dirname(__FILE__) . '/inc/'.$email_template);
$contents =  strtr($templateContents, $templateTags);
if ( mail( $to, $subject, $contents, $headers ) ) {
    $result = array( 'response' => 'success', 'message'=>'<strong>Thank You!</strong>&nbsp; Your email has been delivered.' );
} else {
    $result = array( 'response' => 'error', 'message'=>'<strong>Error!</strong>&nbsp; Cann\'t Send Mail.'  );
}
echo json_encode( $result );
die;
}
```

I just want to alert user is reCatpcha is not ticked and send if it is, also would be nice for all my sendmail.php to work correctly. i.e if name, email, or message is empty echo a message, they seem to be getting missed?

Comment: _“but if it's not ticked my field validators don't work”_ - well what did you expect to happen, when you use `exit` to terminate your script at that point …?

Comment: thank you for that I got it working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$response = 
file_get_contents("https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify? 
secret=SECRETKEY&response=" . $captcha . "&remoteip=" . 
$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);
$s = json_decode($response);
if (!$captcha || $s.success == false) {
echo "Your CAPTCHA response was wrong.";
exit ;
```

Try this, it's possible that accessing this $response directly isn't working, have you tried logging what $response is from the debugger?

Comment: I get two errors

`PHP Recoverable fatal error:  Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string in /home/icallout/public_html/php-script/sendmail.php on line 12
[06-Feb-2019 12:05:41 UTC] PHP Warning:  Use of undefined constant success - assumed 'success' (this will throw an Error in a future version of PHP) in /home/icallout/public_html/php-script/sendmail.php on line 11`

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

session_cache_limiter( 'nocache' );
header( 'Expires: ' . gmdate( 'r', 0 ) );
header( 'Content-type: application/json' );
$to         = 'hi@shanemuirhead.co.uk';  // put your email here
$email_template = 'simple.html';
$subject    = strip_tags($_POST['vsubject']);
$email       = strip_tags($_POST['vemail']);
$name       = strip_tags($_POST['vname']);
$message    = nl2br( htmlspecialchars($_POST['vmessage'], ENT_QUOTES) );
$result     = array();


    if(empty($email)){
        $result = array( 'response' => 'error', 'empty'=>'email', 'message'=>'<strong>Error!</strong>&nbsp; Email is empty.' );
        echo json_encode($result );
        die;
    } 
    if(empty($name)){
        $result = array( 'response' => 'error', 'empty'=>'name', 'message'=>'<strong>Error!</strong>&nbsp; Name is empty.' );
        echo json_encode($result );
        die;
    } 
    if(empty($message)){
         $result = array( 'response' => 'error', 'empty'=>'message', 'message'=>'<strong>Error!</strong>&nbsp; Message body is empty.' );
         echo json_encode($result );
         die;
    }
    if(empty($_POST['g-recaptcha-response']))  {
        $result = array( 'response' => 'error', 'empty'=>'message', 'message'=>'<strong>Error!</strong>&nbsp; Please complete the Captcha.' );
         echo json_encode($result );
         die;
    }

    if(isset($_POST['g-recaptcha-response']) && !empty($_POST['g-recaptcha-response'])) {
        $secret = '6LeSSI0UAAAAAFnwmu5cj7bk4guiaoXXnlID5-C2';
        $verifyResponse = file_get_contents('https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify?secret='.$secret.'&response='.$_POST['g-recaptcha-response']);
        $responseData = json_decode($verifyResponse);
        if($responseData->success == true) {
    $headers  = "From: " . $name . ' <' . $email . '>' . "\r\n";
    $headers .= "Reply-To: ". $email . "\r\n";
    $headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
    $headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8\r\n";
    $templateTags =  array(
        '{{subject}}' => $subject,
        '{{email}}'=>$email,
        '{{message}}'=>$message,
        '{{name}}'=>$name
        );
    $templateContents = file_get_contents( dirname(__FILE__) . '/inc/'.$email_template);
    $contents =  strtr($templateContents, $templateTags);
    if ( mail( $to, $subject, $contents, $headers ) ) {
        $result = array( 'response' => 'success', 'message'=>'<strong>Thank You!</strong>&nbsp; Your email has been delivered.' );
    } else {
        $result = array( 'response' => 'error', 'message'=>'<strong>Error!</strong>&nbsp; Can\'t Send Mail.'  );
    }
    echo json_encode( $result );
    die;

        }
        else
        {
            echo "<p> Sorry verification valid</p>";
        }
   }
?>
```

So with a little playing around and reading my code back to myself I have been able to get everything to work except not sure how to reset to captcha!

So in the end I got all empty field validators to work, after them conditions are met it alerts user to tick the captcha if not done so already and only then will it send form submission and alert user of success message. Only issue now is resetting captcha.

Comment: Resetting captcha i did with JS